# Error on Artisan commands when updating Composer dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a library for Laravel which contains a service provider. I have added this library to another project's `composer.json` file.

The `composer.json` file for the "main project" contains the following scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
```

I can include the library dependency just fine, except for one thing; the `pre-update-cmd` and `post-update-cmd` scripts throw an error and cause me a lot of headaches. When running `sudo composer update` to update the dependencies, I get the following error.

```
$ sudo composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyName\MyProject\MyAwesomeServiceProvider' not found in /Users/Me/dev/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                              
  Class 'MyName\MyProject\MyAwesomeServiceProvider' not found  


Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                         
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyName\MyProject\MyAwesomeServiceProvider' 
  not found in /Users/Me/dev/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146
```

I have Googled around quite a bit before asking this question and read through pretty much everything related that I could find. Apparently this is a known issue that has been discussed in multiple GitHub issues within the Laravel repository. However, I have yet to find a workaround, even after having tried multiple ones.

It appears that the issue is that the Artisan commands bootstrap Laravel, which leads to an error because the service provider is not available at this point - or something like that. Moving the `clear-compiled` command to `post-update-cmd` causes the same error, which surprises me a bit because I thought the service provider would be available at this point.

The only thing that works for me is to manually comment out the line that includes the service provider in `config/app.php` before running `composer update` and then adding it again afterwards. I have been doing this for a few hours, and it is already bothering the heck out of me, and I really cannot believe that this issue is around.

Does anyone know how to work around this error so that I don't get the error that my service provider is not found when updating the Composer dependencies for my project?

**EDIT:**
Here is the `composer.json` file for the library.

```
{
    "name": "my-name/my-project",
    "type": "library",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "My Name",
            "email": "test@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "laravel/framework": "~5.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [],
        "psr-4": {
            "MyName\\MyProject\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `composer.json` file for your library?

Comment: @patricus Sure, I have edited the question with this.

Comment: Thanks. And, just to make sure, you can see your service provider at `vendor/my-name/my-project/src/MyAwesomeServiceProvider.php`, and the first line inside it is `<?php namespace MyName\MyProject;`, correct? And all the casing matches up, as well?

Comment: @patricus Yes, I can confirm both, and the autoloading is also set up properly. This is a known issue, but I haven't found any solution that worked for me. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9678

Comment: One thing that I have discovered, this occurs when you're developing on a package and have the Service Provider registered in `app.providers` but composer doesn't know about it.  In which case `composer dump-autoload -o` has solved this problem by re-generating its paths. Then `composer [install|update]` will work accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Edit

This issue has finally been resolved as of `laravel/framework:v5.2.25` and `laravel/laravel:v5.2.27`, and backported to `laravel/framework:v5.1.33` and `laravel/laravel:v5.1.33`.

This fix includes a change to the Laravel application (`laravel/laravel`), in addition to the Laravel Framework (`laravel/framework`). To implement, you will need to:

1) Update the `scripts` section of your `composer.json` file to match that in the [`laravel/laravel` package](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.29/composer.json). Specifically:

- remove the `pre-update-cmd` section
- in the `post-install-cmd` section, replace `"php artisan clear-compiled"` with `"Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall"`
- in the `post-update-cmd` section, replace `"php artisan clear-compiled"` with `"Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"`

2) Once you have updated your `composer.json`, run a `composer update`. If you only want to update the framework, you can run `composer update laravel/framework`.

---

### Original

After looking over the [Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9678) you posted in the comments, as well as the related issues, you may be in for a bit of a wait. Taylor would like to put a script in `vendor/bin` and change `composer.json` to run that, but it looks like they are waiting for a PR from the community, and won't actually implement this themselves.

You haven't done anything wrong; your autoloading is setup correctly. The issue is with Laravel right now.

Moving the command to the `post-update-cmd` script doesn't work because artisan will always try to load the cache files when they exist. When running the `clear-compiled` command, artisan loads the cache files (part of startup) before it ever tries to delete them.

Your best bet is to manually delete the cache files before artisan gets run. And, you need to do it outside of Laravel/Artisan. So, you can manually delete the files, or you can create a little script to do it and add that to your `composer.json` file (for your main project, not your package).

Files to delete:

- Laravel 5.2:
  `bootstrap/cache/compiled.php`
  `bootstrap/cache/services.php`
- Laravel 5.1:
  `bootstrap/cache/compiled.php`
  `bootstrap/cache/services.json`
- Laravel 5.0:
  `vendor/compiled.php`
  `storage/framework/compiled.php`
  `vendor/services.json`
  `storage/framework/services.json`

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I have played around with these cache files before, but more often than not, they don't exist. In fact, I have never seen the file `compiled.php` within the `cache` directory. I have tried to delete `services.php`, but I still get the error that my service provider class cannot be found. I am not so sure that the problem is related to caching, because the service provider is enabled both in the cached file _and_ in the app configuration, so I guess there is no difference.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the order of things in regards to Composer. I'm not sure where in the update process Composer deletes and regenerates autoload files. I have tried to only keep the `post-update-cmd` script around, but I still get the error. It kind of looks like the autoload files are generated after this script has run, however weird that would be. I kind of suspect that the problem is more related to the autoloading not being set up at the point of running the Artisan commands, but I'm not sure about it. At least it doesn't seem to be related to caching. Any ideas? Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Andy0708 When you do the `composer update`, the autoload files are generated right before the `post-update-cmd` scripts are run ([shown here](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Installer.php#L333-L351)). I don't really have a solution for you, but can you try: 1) delete cache files, 2) `composer update --no-scripts`, and 3) `composer update`?

Comment: Thanks for the link to Composer - that order does indeed make the most sense. I tried what you suggested, but the result is unfortunately the same. I really don't know where to go from here. This is such a big flaw in Laravel that I can't really use this framework. Having to comment out 20 lines of code in 5 different files (for now) and then remove those comments after running `composer update` is just ridiculous, and it seems like a solution is not close. I'm really disappointed that this exists in the most popular PHP framework. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: @Andy0708 It looks like there is finally a resolution. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I heard that it got fixed recently, which is really awesome! I will try to follow your updated answer ASAP and let you know. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

When using `composer install` or `composer update` you can use `--no-scripts` option to skips execution of scripts defined in composer.json.

e. g.: `composer update --no-scripts`.

Source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually thought about that as well, but thought that I might get into some tricky situations when not updating Laravel's cache. I tried it, however, but the result is that I get an error that the service provider class cannot be found. This is a PHP error when loading the page; the Composer update completes without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

this command will ignore command defined in composer.json,otherwise it will excute laravel command which will check if serviceProvider is loaded.

Comment: Check my comment to the other answer that suggested this. :-)

Comment: @Andy0708,i reviewed your question again,now i believe the problem is from autoload,otherwise after you comment that seviceprovider and install it won't appear again,check psr-4 and your definitions

Comment: @Andy0708,maybe you could juse add your library under app folder,and give it a correct namespace like App\CustomLibrary\--->app/CustomLibrary/ServiceProvider

Comment: Autoloading should work fine, because otherwise I wouldn't be able to get my project to run at all using classes from the library. It runs smoothly, just not when updating with Composer. I want the library to be stored in an arbitrary directory and included with Composer. It's true that what you suggested would work, but it's not really what I'm after, because I'm going to be developing this library independently of the project that I am using it in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're simply not including your ServiceProvider. Put this in your **root project**'s `composer.json`:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "MyName\\MyProject\\": "../relative/path/to/serviceprovider/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Composer should take care of the autoloading automatically, right? The class is loaded fine except when running the Artisan commands, so the autoloading seems to work.

Comment: @Andy0708 Composer will only autoload everything in the `app/` directory, unless you tell it to also look in other directories like I did in my answer.

Comment: I took a look at the generated `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`, and I see that my library is being autoloaded correctly. This is because I have specified this in the library's `composer.json` file, which I added to the question a short while ago. Had I not done this, then you would be correct that it wouldn't be autoloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Run This

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```