# How do I fix a missing script in Laravel/Composer Setup?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to setup Laravel which was working before but it stopped running.
I have installed Composer through the newest installer and installed Laravel through Composer with :

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Afterwards I try to create a new project and the creation stops at this point

Those are the versions of everything:

```
C:\Users\josep\Desktop>php -v
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 19:23:59) ( NTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

C:\Users\josep\Desktop>composer -V
Composer version 1.9.1 2019-11-01 17:20:17

C:\Users\josep\Desktop>laravel -v
Laravel Installer 3.0.1
```

I have tested Uninstalling everything and reinstalling everything but nothing works.

```
C:\Users\josep\Desktop>laravel new finalproject
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 14 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.6.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/process (v5.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v5.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v5.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing laravel/installer (v3.0.1): Loading from cache
guzzlehttp/psr7 suggests installing zendframework/zend-httphandlerrunner (Emit PSR-7 responses)
symfony/service-contracts suggests installing symfony/service-implementation
symfony/console suggests installing psr/log (For using the console logger)
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock
guzzlehttp/guzzle suggests installing ext-intl (Required for Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) support)
guzzlehttp/guzzle suggests installing psr/log (Required for using the Log middleware)
Generating autoload files


  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Script "post-root-package-install" is not defined in this package


run-script [--timeout TIMEOUT] [--dev] [--no-dev] [-l|--list] [--] [<script>] [<args>]...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error on Artisan commands when updating Composer dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026380/error-on-artisan-commands-when-updating-composer-dependencies)

Comment: @N69S Sadly it doesn't. I have gone through all the solutions before and none of them fit my case. I have done the installation on an other device and worked perfectly so the way I'm doing the installation is correct.

Comment: You know you dont need laravel installer to install laravel, another solution would be to run this command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <folder_name>` just replace the folder name

Comment: @N69S I have already tried this but when I use that solution I get stuck on another error.